# Metamask not returning the current address

Tags: web3js, metamask, ganache

I am using web3.eth.getcoinbase() function to get the address of the current account but instead, it returns null. Can someone help me with this? This is the code

```
web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
  if (err === null) {
    App.account = account;
    $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
  }
});
```

The entire code is in [here](https://github.com/dappuniversity/election/blob/2019_update/src/js/app.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is outdated. because MetaMask now need to have permission in order or get access to the user's MetaMask.

Change this Code

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
  App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
  App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
  web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
}
```

with this code :

```
if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined'){
  //getting Permission to access. This is for when the user has new MetaMask
  window.ethereum.enable();
  App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

}else if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
  // Acccounts always exposed. This is those who have old version of MetaMask

} else {
  // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
  App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
  web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

}
```

In the new MetaMask there is no such thing like window.web3 . instead you have window.ethereum

If this doesn't work. try to delete the word "window" from everywhere in the new code.